# Returning a valued based on template parameter

Tags: c++

I have declared a class AVL which contains another class AVLNode.
The class AVL contains an insert function. I want insert to return an AVLNode pointer. I'm getting compilation error in this code. What's the error?

```
template<class KeyType>
class AVL
{
    public:
        template<class KeyType>
        class AVLNode{};

        AVLNode<KeyType>* insert(const KeyType& key);
}

template<class KeyType>
AVLNode<KeyType>* AVL<KeyType>::insert(const KeyType& key)
{
    if (m_root == 0)
    {
        m_root = new AVLNode<KeyType>(key);
        return m_root;
    }
    else
        return insert_Helper(key,m_root);
}
```

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AVLNode` class template is a nested class template within `AVL`.  To access it, use `AVL<KeyType>::AVLNode<KeyType>`.  (I'm not sure why you made `AVLNode` a class template; I doubt that's necessary.  Do you really want to have `AVL<int>::AVLNode<float>`?)

Alternatively, you can use a trailing return type:

```
template<typename KeyType>
auto AVL<KeyType>::insert(const KeyType& key) -> AVLNode<KeyType>*
```

This is allowed because you've already qualified this as being a member function of `AVL<KeyType>`, so you can now use names within it freely.

Comment: Not only is it maybe unnecessary for `AVLNode` to be a template, but using the same name `KeyType` for its template argument as for the argument of its enclosing class `AVL` is an error: `declaration of 'KeyType' shadows template parameter`.

Answer (score 0):

@Anton_Golov said you need only one template for your class as it doesn't make sense having a tree for integers while your nodes can be floats. You need only one template. In order to not be confused with them, try to make your class more compact keeping the whole functions inside your class, I assume this is some kind of homework for data structures, or some open source application, so there is no need to write the functionality outside of the class, because you use templates and have to write much stuff outside of the class. Here is your code without errors:

```
template<class KeyType>
class AVL
{
  public:
    class AVLNode{};
    AVLNode m_root;

    AVLNode* insert(const KeyType& key)
    {
        if (m_root == 0)
        {
            m_root = new AVLNode(key);
            return m_root;
        }
        else
            return insert_Helper(key,m_root);
    }
};
```

with `AVL<int> myTree;` you got an **AVL** tree with **int** nodes